# EF core. Fetch data from Db in portions

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have code that retrieves portion of data from db and process it:

```
for (int skip = 0; skip < count; skip += pageSize)
            {
                var portion = db.Items
                    .OrderBy(x=> x.Date)
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var item in portion)
                {
                    item.ModifyDate = now;
                    item.State = status;
                }
            }
```

Thу only reason for this loop is to prevent excessive memory consumption in case of receiving a large amount of data from db. I wonder if there more sophisticated solution to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is db exactly?

Comment: @mrblewog cockroachdb, but I think it's doesn't matter here...

Comment: Well, not quite what I meant. Is it a DbSet, or...?

Comment: @mrblewog oh, sorry. Yes it's a DbSet. I've updated the question.